# Promise to string - [object Object] or [object Promise]?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, promise, ecmascript-6

I execute this code in FF and Chrome.

`Object.prototype.toString.call(Promise.resolve())`

Results:

- Firefox Nightly 44 - `[object Promise]`
- Chrome Canary 48 (with flag) - `[object Promise]`
- Chrome 46 - `[object Object]`

EcmaScript [specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/) in chapter **25.4.4.5 Promise.resolve(x)** quote:

> The resolve function returns either a new promise resolved with the
>   passed argument, or the argument itself if the argument is a promise
>   produced by this constructor.

1. Let C be the this value.
2. If Type(C) is not Object, throw a TypeError exception.
3. If IsPromise(x) is true,

   - Let xConstructor be Get(x, "constructor").
   - ReturnIfAbrupt(xConstructor).
   - If SameValue(xConstructor, C) is true, return x.
4. Let promiseCapability be NewPromiseCapability(C).
5. ReturnIfAbrupt(promiseCapability).
6. Let resolveResult be Call(promiseCapability.[[Resolve]], undefined, «x»).
7. ReturnIfAbrupt(resolveResult).
8. Return promiseCapability.[[Promise]].

So `promiseCapability.[[Promise]]` toString is the result in browser.

PromiseCapability Records have the fields listed in [Table 57](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-promisecapability-records):

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------
| Field Name  | Value     | Meaning                               |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
| [[Promise]] | An object | An object that is usable as a promise |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
```

So `[[Promise]]` is a object and must be `[object Object]`.

Comment: According to http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-promise.prototype-@@tostringtag 'the initial value of the @@toStringTag property is the String value "Promise"'. So `Object.prototype.toString.call(...)` should indeed return "[object Promise]"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah! Welcome to ES2015 :)

This is feature of [`Symbol`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol) implementation in browser. `Symbol` [affect](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object.prototype.tostring) `Object.prototype.toString.call` by `Symbol.toStringTag`:

- Let `tag` be `Get (O, @@toStringTag)`.
- `ReturnIfAbrupt(tag)`
- If `Type(tag)` is not `String`, let tag be `builtinTag`.
- Return the `String` that is the result of concatenating `"[object ", tag, and "]"`.

So `Symbol` make the default string description of an object `obj`:

```
'[object '+obj[Symbol.toStringTag]+']'
```

Get more info about ES2015 aka ES6 `Symbol` from this [article](http://www.2ality.com/2014/12/es6-symbols.html).